# Iterate through an array and check if text exists in sub object in rust

Tags: rust, shopify

I am new to rust and got stuck in getting the below data. Using rust for Shopify payment customisation extension.

Reference code from https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/checkout/payment-customizations/getting-started

This is my input for running `cargo test`

```
r#"
            {
                "cart": {
                    "deliveryGroups": [{
                        "selectedDeliveryOption": {
                            "title": "Test"
                        }
                    }]
                },
                "paymentMethods": [{
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "Test"
                }],
                "paymentCustomization": {
                    "metafield": {
                        "value": "{\"paymentMethod\": \"Test\", \"shippingMethod\": \"Test\"}"
                    }
                }
            }
        "#
```

I need to check if the `cart.deliveryGroups.iter().selectedDeliveryOption.title == 'Test'`. If yes, return true else false.

This is the is code i am using to check. using Shopify `#[shopify_function]` to convert the data to input field with object data.

```
let is_available = input
        .cart
        .delivery_groups
        .iter()
        .find(|&method| {
            method
                .selected_delivery_option
                .unwrap()
                .title
                .contains('Test')
        })
        .map(|method| {
            true
        });
```

Is the above code to get find the title using iter method correct or there is another way to do this ?

Tried to get the data using the above code, but always getting error.

Current error is

```
error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'option_result_contains'
  --> src/main.rs:48:18
   |
48 |                 .contains('Test')
   |                  ^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: see issue #62358 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/62358> for more information
```

test.rs https://codeshare.io/xvQKKk
main.rs https://codeshare.io/X8Jbbo

```
// Filter the shipping method to disable
    let shipping_method = input
        .cart
        .delivery_groups
        .iter()
        .find(|&method| {
            println!("Selected delivery option {:?}", method.selected_delivery_option);
            true
        });

    println!("shippping method {:?}", shipping_method);
```

The above code give output as

```
Selected delivery option Some(InputCartDeliveryGroupsSelectedDeliveryOption { title: Some("Another delivery method") })
shippping method Some(InputCartDeliveryGroups { selected_delivery_option: Some(InputCartDeliveryGroupsSelectedDeliveryOption { title: Some("Another delivery method") }) })
```

Comment: What error? Are you using a particular library to parse the json? You haven't given us enough to help here.

Comment: I am using shopify extensions. using https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/checkout/payment-customizations/getting-started tutorial. Editing the code to check if shipping method exists or not instead of the total amount

Comment: using `#[shopify_function]`, the input is getting converted to object format. when i run the `cargo test`, getting errors. Need to know if the above code is correct or need to change

Comment: @jmb i just want to check if `cart.delivery_groups.iter().selected_delivery_option.title == 'Test'` is true or false... how can we do that in rust.  After looping i am able to get selected_delivery_option, but to get title from selected_delivery_option, i am not able to understand how to do that in rust.

Comment: From the error messages, `selected_delivery_option.title` is visibly an `Option<String>` or an `Option<&str>`. So you can just compare: `selected_delivery_option.title == Some ("Test")` or `selected_delivery_option.title == Some ("Test".to_string())`.

Comment: ```let selected = method.selected_delivery_option.as_ref().unwrap();
            selected.title ==  Some(config.shipping_method.to_string())``` works... need to run test cases

Comment: @cafce25 I never said otherwise, but since there is an easy fix that doesn't require nightly, it's better to compare directly with `Some`.

Comment: @Jmb i think the above code is not correct. I need something good for production. The above code seems to be error some. (Using unwrap is a bad practice)